# Fusion Table Layer with polygons AND markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

Using Google Maps API v3

I have a map with the countries coloured using polygons from a Fusion Table Layer. When a polygon is clicked it opens the default Fusion Table info window which has been configured in the web interface.

Some of the countries can't be seen at certain zoom levels so I'd like these countries to have a polygon AND marker, which when clicked open the default Fusion Table info window. I did add a standard map marker but there is no way to open the Fusion Table info window when clicked.

I've read through the docs and looked at the examples but can't see how this is achieved. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this working.

I created a second Fusion Table layer and instead of selecting the KML column I selected the Longitude column with a WHERE clause specifying the smaller countries. This renders a layer with markers on the smaller countries which sits on top of the polygon layer.

The only downside is that both the polygon and marker are both clickable which could open duplicate default Fusion Table info windows. Not a major problem though.

Comment: If you use {suppressInfoWindows:true} and create your own infowindow, you can 1. use the infoWindowHtml property in the click listener to access the formatted infowindow content, and 2. only have one infowindow at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the "default FusionTables infowindow" from an external click event.  You can query the FusionTable from your page and display an infowindow containing the same information on a click on a Google Maps API marker (or a sidebar entry).

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html) (opening infowindow from sidebar click, not a marker, as you didn't provide an example)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip. I had customised the Fusion Table info window from the web interface. I appreciate I can get the same information but am I right in thinking that your solution wouldn't pick up this formatting?

Comment: That is correct.  To have all the infowindows formatted the same, you have to use the click listener on the table to open your own infowindow, rather than the default one. I haven't found a way to access the formatted infowindow contents except from a click listener on the map, which can't be triggered externally.  You can format the infowindow that you display using this technique the same as the one you customized in the Fusion Table web interface.